# any way how to define msb:lsb range as parameter?

Tags: system-verilog

having tons of registers defined in my hardware, containing bit fields, I wanted to 'name' those registers and access in SystemVerilog the bit fields using their names instead of msb:lsb format. So, I made a new package, and declared constant parameters inside, and as well tried those which describe range. Something like this:

```
package VmeAddressMap;
   parameter SYS_INTCONFIG = 32'h00000044;
   parameter RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA = 31:16;
   parameter RSYS_INTCONFIGENABLE = 15:0;
endpackage // VmeAddressMap
```

quite evidently, this does not work. So I came with a 'hybrid' solution, i.e. simple constants stay in package, and for ranges I made another file, which contains macros:

package file:

```
package VmeAddressMap;
   parameter SYS_INTCONFIG = 32'h00000044;
endpackage // VmeAddressMap
```

macro file:

```
`define RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA 31:16
`define RSYS_INTCONFIGENABLE 15:0
```

this solution permits me to do things as follow (Read is a task reading data through VME bus):

```
Read(SYS_INTCONFIG);
`CHECK_EQUAL(LastVmeReadData_b32[`RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA], 15,
           "IRQ setup invalid");
```

This works, and does what I want. However I don't like it. In particular mixing macros with SystemVerilog style of description.

Is there a way how to accomplish the same task directly in the package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what the UVM register abstraction layer does for you. You define fields giving them a name, bit width, and other attributes. Those fields are grouped into a registers, and registers are grouped into blocks with addresses and offsets.

Now that I've told you that, here's a simple solution that does what you are looking for using the `let` construct.

```
package VmeAddressMap;
   parameter SYS_INTCONFIG = 32'h00000044;
   let RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA(field) = field[31:16];
   let RSYS_INTCONFIGENABLE(field) = field[15:0];
endpackage // VmeAddressMap
```

But now you have to put the range in front of the variable.

```
`CHECK_EQUAL(RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA(LastVmeReadData_b32), 15,
           "IRQ setup invalid");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use one parameter for the MSB and another for the LSB.

```
parameter RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA_MSB = 31;
parameter RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA_LSB = 16;

LastVmeReadData_b32[RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA_MSB:RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA_LSB]
```

That is a bit unwieldy, so if everything is 16 bits wide you can just define the LSB:

```
parameter RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA = 16;

LastVmeReadData_b32[RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA +: 16]
```

Or, you can use a struct:

```
typedef struct packed {
  logic [15:0] RSYS_INTCONFIGRORA;
  logic [15:0] RSYS_INTCONFIGENABLE;
} some_register_t;
```

You can further make a `union` with that struct if some parts of the design need to interact with the whole register object and others with just the bit fields.

These register structs can be built up into a much larger register map struct.

If you are using `UVM` then you should be building up a `RAL` module of your registers